# How can l use echo with my code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $results=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM new where date>'$date' and erisim='1'   group by date_format(tarih,'%Y-%m') ");
   $array=mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC);

    echo $array[''];
```

what should l have to filled inside $array[''] to get count values per month?

Answer (score 6):

```
 $results=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as Total FROM new where year(date)='$ss' and erisim='1'      group by date_format(tarih,'%Y-%m') ");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo  $row["Total"] ;
 }
```